# msxml loadXML API error handling ambiguity

Tags: c++, winapi, msxml6

I have a problem with understanding msxml API, particularly the 'IXMLDOMDocument::loadXML' function. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms751210(v%3Dvs.85)), function returns HRESULT. When succeeded, it should return 'S_OK' which is a zero, also according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/common-hresult-values). But I've found different behaviour...

I got the code:

```
try {
  HRESULT res = xml->loadXML(xml_text);
  bool ret = SUCCEEDED(res);
}
catch (_com_error& ex) {
 //some error handling
}
```

If I load a valid xml file, then surprisingly 'res' is '-1' and the 'ret' becomes 'false'. It indicates that it failed to load that xml file. However, at the same time, there is no exception thrown... If I ignore returned value, and start processing the file, it turns out that xml file was loaded successfully...

It seems that exception handling is a proper way to verify if a file was loaded: no exception means loaded file. But I cannot understand, why the return values are messed up?

Finally, I cannot understand, why the exception handling is not mentioned in the documentation?

Can anybody explain to me that situation? Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what...

Comment: It looks like you are using some kind of wrapper that translates the hresult into c++ exceptions and returns the VARIANT_BOOL output parameter as the return value.

Comment: You're right, I missed that completely... But these wrapper functions were generated by VC++ compiler according to documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757018(v=vs.85)

Still, it seems strange for me, because it's is done by microsoft tools...

Comment: Looking at the generated msxml6.tli file, I've found that 'save' function returns proper 'HRESULT' but 'load' returns 'VARIANT_BOOL'. Is there any logic in that?

Comment: Yes, the logic is that if the method has an out parameter it gets turned into the return value, otherwise nothing changes, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757016(v=vs.85)

Comment: Thank You a lot! That is what I was looking for. And forgive me stupid questions, but I'm new to WinApi.